# Android - how to add a header to all the pages?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add the same header for navigation to all the pages on the app.

It should look something like this:

```
----------------------------
  Button1 Button2 Button3
----------------------------

Content content content 
...
```

How can I do that?

So far I found something like this to my existing layouts:

```
<include android:id="@+id/header"
         layout="@layout/my_header"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
```

But I am not sure how to put the buttons across the top of the header or how to structure that layout.

Any idea what I can do?

Also, for the buttons that will be present on the header, should I add a listener to every page for each of those buttons?

Also, I made this header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:padding="5dip">

 <Button android:id="@+id/home"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Home"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

 <Button android:id="@+id/questions"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="My Questions"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" /> 

 <Button android:id="@+id/businesses"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="My Businesses"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />  

 <Button android:id="@+id/learn"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Learning Center"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />  


 <Button android:id="@+id/extra_help"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Extra Help"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />  
</RelativeLayout>
```

But all the buttons show up on top of each other instead of next to each other.  How could that be solved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dip">

<Button android:id="@+id/home"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Home"
 />

<Button android:id="@+id/questions"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="My Questions"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home"  /> 

<Button android:id="@+id/businesses"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="My Businesses"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/questions" />  

 <Button android:id="@+id/learn"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Learning Center"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/businesses" />  


<Button android:id="@+id/extra_help"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Extra Help"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/learn"/>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the XML `<include>` tag.  See the following on the [dev site](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html).

Example Code:

The header XML: (header.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The activity using the header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/header" />  <<<(this is the layout file you want to include)

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />

    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

As for listeners... yes you need to add them to every page that uses the headers.  You might want to extend the activity class and put in all the code you need to repeat for each page.  Then just extend your activity class for each of your pages.

Hope this helps.  (sorry for the delay getting back to this... work has been crazy busy)

Comment: I am confused - I already use the include tag in the code I used above.  What is different?

Comment: I will post some code later this morning when I get a minute.